# How do I bundle multiple installers?

Tags: python-2.7, installation

I have two files that I would like to bundle together and I really do not know how to start.

The first file is Python which is a .msi and the other is an extension of python which is an .exe file.

How can I get Python to install first then the .exe extension to download second?

What programs can I use to package these programs?

Comment: try wixtoolset: http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work with wix!